# Dynamically add an image view to a ScrollView

Tags: android

I am trying to make an app that dynamically loads images  from my computer to a imageview on a scroll view.
i want to make it simillar to instagram (with likes).
im using ftp to download the images from my computer.

I need some ideas that will direct me with the
code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is a simple workflow:

1. Use `FTPClient` from `org.apache.commons.net.ftp` package to download file from FTP. The example snippet can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053513/howto-do-a-simple-ftp-get-file-on-android)
2. Once you've got input stream, use [BitmapFactory.decodeStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) to convert it to a `Bitmap`
3. After that you can use [setImageBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29) method to set the source for the `ImageView`.
4. Since `ScrollView` can have only one children, you can have a following layout structure, for example: `ScrollView` -> vertical `LinearLayout` with id = `container`.
5. Add all the needed `ImageViews` to `container` by calling `addView` method.