# Reading txt file from an ftp server and returning it from AsyncTask

Tags: android, ftp, android-asynctask, return-value

I have a `txt file` in my `ftp server`. And all I want to do is reading that file, retrieve the contents and save it as a string by using `AsyncTask`. As I understand from the logcat, I'm able to connect `ftp server` and I can change directory. But I cannot read the context of the text file, and I don't know how to return it from the my `AsyncTask` class.

And these are my codes:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.ftpdenemeleri;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FtpAsync task1 = new FtpAsync();
    task1.execute();

    }
}
```

**FtpAsync.java**

```
package com.example.ftpdenemeleri;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPCmd;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class FtpAsync extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String>{

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
   super.onPreExecute();      
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {
        ftpClient.connect("hostname", 21);

        System.out.println(ftpClient.getReplyString());
        ftpClient.sendCommand(FTPCmd.USER, "user");
        System.out.println(ftpClient.getReplyString());
        ftpClient.sendCommand(FTPCmd.PASS, "pass");
        System.out.println(ftpClient.getReplyString());
        ftpClient.sendCommand(FTPCmd.CWD, "/home/www/bitirme");
        InputStream is = new      BufferedInputStream(ftpClient.retrieveFileStream("beaglesays.txt")); 
        System.out.println("Input Stream has opened.");

      } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
    return null; 
}

protected void onPostExecute() {
        // TODO: check this.exception 
        // TODO: do something with the feed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to fully read an InputStream into a String. The easiest one would be to use [`IOUtils.toString()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) from [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/).

So, assuming that, the changes would be to return said string from `doInBackground()` and receive it in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: I've tried using IOUtils.toString() but i guess i couldn't make it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code must be like :

```
 package com.example.ftpdenemeleri;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPCmd;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class FtpAsync extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String>{

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();      
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
try {
    ftpClient.connect("hostname", 21);

    System.out.println(ftpClient.getReplyString());
    ftpClient.sendCommand(FTPCmd.USER, "user");
    System.out.println(ftpClient.getReplyString());
    ftpClient.sendCommand(FTPCmd.PASS, "pass");
    System.out.println(ftpClient.getReplyString());
    ftpClient.sendCommand(FTPCmd.CWD, "/home/www/bitirme");
    InputStream is = new           BufferedInputStream(ftpClient.retrieveFileStream("beaglesays.txt")); 
    System.out.println("Input Stream has opened.");

Scanner s = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A"); // Convert your stream into string
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : ""; //send the string to onPostExecute()


  } catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
}
return null; 
}


protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO: check this.exception 
    // TODO: do something with the feed
Log.i("Result : ",result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @AosKhalifa, when i try to use scanner like your suggestion, rest of the code become unreachable. I've tested it by using System.out.println and i got "unreachable code" warning.

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) clearly. 
Few things:
(1) Similar question: [Howto do a simple ftp get file on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053513/howto-do-a-simple-ftp-get-file-on-android) 
(2) Once you get content in doInBackground() - return the content as String(at present you are returning null). 
(3) Add parameter in onPostExecute(String result) and this will the content of the file.

Comment: I've seen that question, but since i'm kinda new to java and android, i didn't know what to do with InputStream and InputStreamReader, that's the point that i didn't understand. About AsyncTask, you are right, i still can't get how to pass string to onPostExecute from doInBackground.